# Sticky footer CSS make the jQuery widgets move from their respective positions on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/QGUbq/)
I have implemented a sticky footer using CSS3.It works fine for the footer.But in the same page I have datepickers and other jquery widgets which popout from elements.

The problem occurs when scrolling.

On scrolling the widgets also move from their corresponding position that is not needed because if i have two datepickers one after other and open the first and scroll the calendar position may change to second one's calendar position and cause usability issues.

when removing the sticky footer style especially

```
body {
    height : 100%;
}
```

everything works fine

Comment: Why your datepicker is outside your main wrapper ?

Comment: I dnt know :( .Isn't that how it should be? I am new to this.

Comment: If you want it to scroll properly , it must be inside of relative positioned container , so that how datepicker will folow it's parent container when scrolled.

Comment: I assume that script you are using appending this datepicker to a body tag and positioning it by ofset x & y , so you need to inspect your datepicker script at first place

Comment: Yes . That,s right . The datepicker is appended to the body tag

Comment: But the scroll issue is not only with datepicker but all the popups and dialogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue.
There was an

`.mainContainer, .dashBoard {
    float: none !important;
    overflow:auto !important;
}`

and on removing the overflow auto the calendars remained their corresponding positions on scrolling.
The [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chanchalstack/jLeaV/1/) .

But dont know the reason .Can any one explain the reason pls.